# Applet not running

Tags: java, window, applet

Im fairly new to java and applet but when I run my code I expect to be greeted with some sort of applet window however nothing happens when I run. What am I doing wrong, or am I missing something ?

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;

public class Tennis extends Applet {
    final int W = 700, H = 500;

    public void init(){
        this.resize(W,H);

    }

    public void paint (Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        super.print(g);

    }

    public void update (Graphics g){
        paint(g);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

    }

}
```

Comment: Applets are dead (they've been officially deprecated) and the applet plugin is no longer supported by just about any browsers.  Applets were originally intended to be displayed within a html page, so it's not unsurprising not to see a window. Maybe start with [How to Make Frames (Main Windows)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) instead ... or better yet, take the time to learn JavaFX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Java Client Roadmap Update](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdate2018mar-4414431.pdf)

> During the past five years, most browser vendors have withdrawn
> support for plugins such as Flash, Silverlight, and Java in their
> products. Supporting Java Applets in browsers was only possible as
> long as browser vendors were committed to supporting standards based
> plugins. By late 2015, many browser vendors had either removed or
> announced timelines for the removal of standards-based plugin support,
> while some introduced proprietary browser-specific extension APIs.
> Consequently:
>
> - Existing Applet support in Java SE 8 will continue through March 2019, after    which it may be removed at any time.
> - Oracle announced in January 2016 that Applets would be deprecated in Java SE 9,    and removed from Java SE 11 (18.9).

If you have Java 8 or prior installed with necessary files. You can try [appletviewer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/appletviewer.html)